# My iCustom indicator changes more frequently in EA than chart

Tags: mql4, indicator, metatrader4, forex

I am using a custom indicator that draws up and down arrows for fractals.
Below is one the hour timeframe and the indicator is working correctly.

[image: Fractals]

The problem is when I call the indicator using below code in an EA and monitor those values to detect changes OnTick():

```
static double firstUpArrowValue = 2147483647;
static double firstDownArrowValue = 2147483647;
static bool firstUpArrowIsSet = false;
static bool firstDownArrowIsSet = false;

int OnInit() {

  return (INIT_SUCCEEDED);
}
void OnTick() {


  double UpArrowValue = iCustom(_Symbol, PERIOD_H1, "Fractals ST Patterns", 1, 10.0, 0, 1);
  double DownArrowValue = iCustom(_Symbol, PERIOD_H1, "Fractals ST Patterns", 1, 10.0, 1, 1);

  UpArrowValue = NormalizeDouble(UpArrowValue, Digits);
  DownArrowValue = NormalizeDouble(DownArrowValue, Digits);

  if (UpArrowValue != 2147483647 && !firstUpArrowIsSet) {

    //this is our first up arrow
    firstUpArrowValue = UpArrowValue;
    firstUpArrowIsSet = True;
    Print(GetDateAndTime() + " First Up Arrow: " + firstUpArrowValue);
  }

  if (firstUpArrowIsSet && (UpArrowValue != firstUpArrowValue) && (UpArrowValue != 2147483647)) {

    //up arrow value changed
    Print(GetDateAndTime() + " Up Arrow Value Changed: " + UpArrowValue);
    firstUpArrowValue = UpArrowValue;
  }

}

string GetDateAndTime() {
  return (string(Year()) + "-" + StringFormat("%02d", Month()) + "-" + StringFormat("%02d", Day()) + " " + StringFormat("%02d", Hour()) + ":" + StringFormat("%02d", Minute()));
}
```

Here is the indicator code as well (modified for cleaner variable names and translated Russian):

```
//+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                       Fractals ST patterns         |
//|                                       Skype:                       |
//|                                       E-mail: stpatterns@gmail.com |
//+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
#property copyright "Copyright by Vladimir Poltoratskiy"

#property strict
#property indicator_chart_window
#property indicator_buffers 2
#property indicator_color1 clrBlue;
#property indicator_width1 1;
#property indicator_color2 clrRed;
#property indicator_width2 1;

input int bars_surrounding = 1; //Bars around
extern double arrow_offset = 10; //Arrow offset

double UP[];
double DN[];
int kod_Arrow_Up = 217;
int kod_Arrow_Down = 218;

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Custom indicator initialization function                         |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int OnInit() {

  //--- indicator buffers mapping
  arrow_offset *= Point;
  SetIndexBuffer(0, UP);
  SetIndexBuffer(1, DN);
  SetIndexStyle(0, DRAW_ARROW, EMPTY);
  SetIndexStyle(1, DRAW_ARROW, EMPTY);
  SetIndexArrow(0, kod_Arrow_Up);
  SetIndexArrow(1, kod_Arrow_Down);

  //---
  return (INIT_SUCCEEDED);
}

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert deinitialization function                                 |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnDeinit(const int reason) {
  //---

}
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Custom indicator iteration function                              |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int OnCalculate(const int rates_total,
  const int prev_calculated,
    const datetime & time[],
      const double & open[],
        const double & high[],
          const double & low[],
            const double & close[],
              const long & tick_volume[],
                const long & volume[],
                  const int & spread[]) {
  //---
  int i, j;
  int lim;

  if (prev_calculated == 0) {
    lim = rates_total - bars_surrounding - 10;
  } else {
    lim = bars_surrounding + 2;
  }

  for (i = 0; i <= lim; i++) {
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    //--- LOWER Fractal
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    DN[i] = EMPTY_VALUE;
    bool R_Plecho = true; //Check for fulfillment of the condition RIGHT from the current bar
    bool L_Plecho = true; //Check for fulfillment of the condition to the left of the current bar
    //---
    //--- Determine whether the candle is the peak in relation to the standing next to the left
    for (j = i + 1; j <= i + bars_surrounding; j++)
      if (NormalizeDouble(Low[j], Digits) < NormalizeDouble(Low[i], Digits)) {
        L_Plecho = false;
        break;
      }
    if (L_Plecho)
      if (i >= bars_surrounding) {
        for (j = i - 1; j >= 0 && j >= i - bars_surrounding; j--)
          if (NormalizeDouble(Low[j], Digits) < NormalizeDouble(Low[i], Digits)) {
            R_Plecho = false;
            break;
          }
      }
    else R_Plecho = false;
    if (R_Plecho && L_Plecho) DN[i] = Low[i] - arrow_offset;
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    //--- UPPER fractal
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    UP[i] = EMPTY_VALUE;
    R_Plecho = true; //Check for fulfillment of the condition RIGHT from the current bar
    L_Plecho = true; //Check for fulfillment of the condition to the left of the current bar
    //---
    //--- Check for fulfillment of the condition to the left of the current bar
    for (j = i + 1; j <= i + bars_surrounding; j++)
      if (NormalizeDouble(High[j], Digits) > NormalizeDouble(High[i], Digits)) {
        L_Plecho = false;
        break;
      }
    if (L_Plecho)
      if (i >= bars_surrounding) {
        for (j = i - 1; j >= 0 && j >= i - bars_surrounding; j--)
          if (NormalizeDouble(High[j], Digits) > NormalizeDouble(High[i], Digits)) {
            R_Plecho = false;
            break;
          }
      }
    else R_Plecho = false;
    if (R_Plecho && L_Plecho) UP[i] = High[i] + arrow_offset;
  }

  return (rates_total);
}
```

I see the following changes:

> 2019.02.19 19:00:00  FractalReader EURUSD,H1: 2019-02-19 19:00 Up Arrow Value Changed: 1.1366
>
> 2019.02.19 18:00:00  FractalReader EURUSD,H1: 2019-02-19 18:00 Up Arrow Value Changed: 1.1352
>
> 2019.02.19 17:00:00  FractalReader EURUSD,H1: 2019-02-19 17:00 Up Arrow Value Changed: 1.1349
>
> 2019.02.19 16:00:00  FractalReader EURUSD,H1: 2019-02-19 16:00 Up Arrow Value Changed: 1.1331
>
> 2019.02.19 15:00:00  FractalReader EURUSD,H1: 2019-02-19 15:00 Up Arrow Value Changed: 1.131
>
> 2019.02.19 11:00:00  FractalReader EURUSD,H1: 2019-02-19 11:00 Up Arrow Value Changed: 1.1334
>
> 2019.02.19 10:00:00  FractalReader EURUSD,H1: 2019-02-19 10:00 Up Arrow Value Changed: 1.1333
>
> 2019.02.19 09:00:00  FractalReader EURUSD,H1: 2019-02-19 09:00 Up Arrow Value Changed: 1.1314
>
> 2019.02.19 07:00:00  FractalReader EURUSD,H1: 2019-02-19 07:00 Up Arrow Value Changed: 1.1309
>
> 2019.02.19 02:02:00  FractalReader EURUSD,H1: 2019-02-19 02:02 Up Arrow Value Changed: 1.1323
>
> 2019.02.19 01:00:00  FractalReader EURUSD,H1: 2019-02-19 01:00 First Up Arrow: 1.1322
>
> 2019.02.19 00:00:00  FractalReader EURUSD,H1: 2019-02-19 00:00 First Down Arrow: 1.1298

Not all of the above resulted in an arrow being drawn, but all of the arrows drawn are one of those lines.  I believe this is because it is using the current bar being drawn to find a fractal.  At some point in the current bars rendering it may form a fractal, but not necessarily when it is done and moved onto the next time period.

How can I figure out when a signal change results in an arrow being drawn?  I want to completely ignore signals from the current bar because it gives me extra results.  Is there a way to edit the EA so it only uses the previous 3 bars instead of current bar and the previous 2 ?

Comment: Do you have a MCVE? do you call the bar#1 only or until you obtain a non-empty value? Do you know the logic of your fractal indicator, is it different from the standard fractal indicator by B.Williams?

Comment: @DanielKniaz have added the MCVE.  I keep checking for a non-empty value and when the value has changed I print it.  Yes, it is different than the standard fractal indicator by B. Williams.  The indicator only checks 1 bar to the left or right not 2.  After watching it in action, the reason I am getting more indicator value changes than arrows is because the indicator is watching the current bar being drawn.  So at one point in the current bars history it may form a fractal, but after the timeperiod plays out, it may fail to form a fractal.

Comment: I have slightly tweaked the question..how to ignore the bar being drawn so only fully formed bars are used.

Comment: As far as I understand fractals and your problem, you check bar#1. but its value can be changed because of bar#0 that is in process. It seems that bar#2 should not change if you described the situation correctly. On the other hand it could be quite late for you.

Comment: @DanielKniaz - yes, you understand it correctly.  No I need to figure out how to shift everything to the left one so bar #0 is ignored.

Comment: probably your indicator uses bar#0, does it? if so, you cannot ignore it unless you do not call the indicator.

Comment: @DanielKniaz I have posted the indicator code - any chance you can take a look at that and advise how to ignore 0.  Looking at it I feel like I just need to increment one of the counters, but there are a few.

Comment: Yes, you should drop/comment both sections with decrementing `j`, only incrementing. `for (j = i - 1; j >= 0 && j >= i - bars_surrounding; j--)` and down the loop should be commented. But of course this would change the logic of the indicator and its output. Maybe the best way is to have two parameters, one for going left (as it is) and another for going right(or going right if and only if 'j=i-1>0' but in such case historical observations would be different from real time. Fractals are not the best instrument to obtain reasonable and stable data I am afraid

Comment: @DanielKniaz - can you post these modifications as a seperate answer with the full modified indicator code so I can award the bounty ?

Comment: Thank you for approving!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#property strict
#property indicator_chart_window
#property indicator_buffers 2
#property indicator_color1 clrBlue;
#property indicator_width1 1;
#property indicator_color2 clrRed;
#property indicator_width2 1;

input int bars_surrounding = 1; //Bars around
input bool check_right=true;    //check Right candles
extern double arrow_offset = 10; //Arrow offset

double UP[];
double DN[];
int kod_Arrow_Up = 217;int kod_Arrow_Down = 218;
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Custom indicator initialization function                         |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int OnInit() {

  //--- indicator buffers mapping
  arrow_offset *= Point;
  SetIndexBuffer(0, UP);
  SetIndexBuffer(1, DN);
  SetIndexStyle(0, DRAW_ARROW, EMPTY);
  SetIndexStyle(1, DRAW_ARROW, EMPTY);
  SetIndexArrow(0, kod_Arrow_Up);
  SetIndexArrow(1, kod_Arrow_Down);

  //---
  return (INIT_SUCCEEDED);
}

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert deinitialization function                                 |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnDeinit(const int reason) {
  //---

}
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Custom indicator iteration function                              |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int OnCalculate(const int rates_total,
                const int prev_calculated,
                const datetime & time[],
                const double & open[],
                const double & high[],
                const double & low[],
                const double & close[],
                const long & tick_volume[],
                const long & volume[],
                const int & spread[]) {
  //---
  int i, j;
  int lim;

  if (prev_calculated == 0) {
    lim = rates_total - bars_surrounding - 10;
  } else {
    lim = bars_surrounding + 2;
  }

  for (i = 0; i <= lim; i++) {
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    //--- LOWER Fractal
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    DN[i] = EMPTY_VALUE;
    bool R_Plecho = true; //Check for fulfillment of the condition RIGHT from the current bar
    bool L_Plecho = true; //Check for fulfillment of the condition to the left of the current bar
    //---
    //--- Determine whether the candle is the peak in relation to the standing next to the left
    for (j = i + 1; j <= i + bars_surrounding; j++)
      if (low[j] < low[i]) {
        L_Plecho = false;
        break;
      }
    if (L_Plecho)
      if (i >= bars_surrounding && check_right) {
        for (j = i - 1; j >= 0 && j >= i - bars_surrounding; j--)
          if (low[j] < low[i]) {
            R_Plecho = false;
            break;
          }
      }
    //else R_Plecho = false;//no need because L_shoulder is left
    if (R_Plecho && L_Plecho) DN[i] = Low[i] - arrow_offset;
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    //--- UPPER fractal
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    UP[i] = EMPTY_VALUE;
    R_Plecho = true; //Check for fulfillment of the condition RIGHT from the current bar
    L_Plecho = true; //Check for fulfillment of the condition to the left of the current bar
    //---
    //--- Check for fulfillment of the condition to the left of the current bar
    for (j = i + 1; j <= i + bars_surrounding; j++)
      if (high[j] > high[i]) {
        L_Plecho = false;
        break;
      }
    if (L_Plecho)
      if (i >= bars_surrounding && check_right) {
        for (j = i - 1; j >= 0 && j >= i - bars_surrounding; j--)
          if (high[j] > high[i]) {
            R_Plecho = false;
            break;
          }
      }
    //else R_Plecho = false;
    if (R_Plecho && L_Plecho) UP[i] = High[i] + arrow_offset;
  }

  return (rates_total);
}
```

And do not forget to call `iCustom(_Symbol,0,"Fractals ST Patterns",1,false,10,0,1)` by the way parameter 10 might be omitted as it is used for drawing